# batch .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm moving servers and cleaning up the url's a bit at the same time.

current urls are:

```
secure.mydomain.com/onlinestore/product.php?productid=12345
```

changing it to:

```
mydomain.com/product.php?productid=12345
```

wondering if I can do something in htaccess so if someone clicks an old link/bookmark they get redirected to the new page.

Not worried about making the dynamic part be SEO friendly just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It forces a redirect with a "moved permanently" header.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secure\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule onlinestore/product\.php http://mydomain.com/product.php [L,R=301,QSA]
```

**Edit** was missing some `/` in the `RewriteCond`
**Edit2** Redirect wasn't going to the correct domain

Comment: doesn't seem to work, tried a few different variations and all just give me server not found error.

Comment: @Fadzy Try it now.  I forgot that the redirect is happening across 2 domain names so the full domain has to appear in the rewrite target.

Comment: thanks that did the trick... I also had to add ServerAlias *.domain.com to httpd.conf